# Sencha touch app building

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I was put in charge of learning this and well I have read and tried to understand it all.  I am lost in how to get it started and optimized. I need to achieve a window at startup that is menu based and takes you to different components.  I think I have the photo galleries sorted out just now sure how to link to the startup window.
[examples](http://justawebbie.freehostingcloud.com/sencha-touch-help.html)

Answer (score 1):

I used this tutorial when I was trying to learn - http://miamicoder.com/2011/writing-a-sencha-touch-mvc-application/

The learning curve is quite steep but once you understand it it's a really good bit of kit to know your way around.

If you don't already understand the MVC (Model View Controller) architecture then it's going to be a bit tricky but the tutorial explains it all pretty well.

My advice would be start following the tutorial. Stick to it, get it working and THEN adapt it.

Good luck.

Comment: I got it working it was easy just copy code and such but the notes MVC is nothing like what I am trying to build. I just get confused when I try to change it to fit my needs. thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

With Sencha Touch 2, the team have created a bunch of guides which hopefully help ease the pain when trying to learn the framework.

I suggest you first take a look at the [Getting Started Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started), and then move onto the [Building your first App Guide](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/first_app). These both should give you a kick start on where to start.

After that, I would definitely recommend you take a look at the code of their various examples, and then try modifying it. When I was first learning the framework (and JavaScript in general) I found that taking existing code and modifying it was definitely the easiest way of learning. Obviously this varies from person-to-person, but it is always a good step.

Much of their documentation have previews and examples which you can actually edit the code inline, which I have found very useful in the past. You can view an example of this [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.Button).

The Touch [Forums](http://www.sencha.com/forum/forumdisplay.php?89-Sencha-Touch-2.x-Forums) are very active. Almost all topics get responded to within hours, and I have never seen a post which was never responded to.

Comment: I have read it all and tried to manipulate the code guess I am just dumb when it comes to this but I have to keep trying.  Thank you for all you help.  I will have to keep plugging at it and hope I can understand it sooner rather than later.